# Как изменить курсор на курсор ожидания?

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

Есть приложение WinForms, на нем одна форма. Я пытаюсь изменить курсор на курсор ожидания во время выполнения метода:

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
```

Но курсор ожидания только в области формы, за ее пределами - это обычный курсор. Программа иногда может быть свернута в трей. Можно ли курсор изменить на курсор ожидания глобально, чтобы он был не только в пределах формы?

Comment: Показывайте ожидание анимированной иконкой в трее. Изменять курсор глобально не стоит — он может быть над окном другой программы, и тогда пользователь будет думать, что это не вы "вращающееся кольцо/песочные часы" показали, а та программа.

Comment: так у вас ожидает только ваша программа, то есть за пределеми вашей программы никакого ожидания нет, смысл там покажывать курсор ожидания?

Comment: это форма только с drop zone. После перетаскивания файла идет обработка  некоторое время и пользователь должен понимать, что идет обработка. Вариант с анимированной иконкой в трее - идея мне очень понравилась.

Comment: Так может на самой форме информировать что идет обработка?

Comment: Нет, т.к. форма может быть свернута